# Zend Google Calendar API - Add Event is One Hour off

Tags: zend-framework, timezone, google-calendar-api

When I add an event using the Zend API the time is one hour off on the summer daylight savings time months.

The string I use for the date to add is "2012-10-02T06:00:00-05:00".  I'm in the Eastern timezone and my Google Calendar is also setup for Eastern, but the time displays as 7am.
I've also tried "2012-10-02T06:00:00.000-05:00".

I've also tried using date_default_timezone_set("America/Detroit").

Any ideas?  I've been researching and trying to fix this for awhile now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do apply a timezone identifier to my entries. I use -05:00  --> "2012-10-02T06:00:00-05:00"

I thought setTimezone only applies to Zend_Date

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry` allows you to call `getTimezone()` and `setTimezone()` also you should be able to apply a timezone identifier to your entry or a UTC offset.

```
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T10:30:00.0z" //z is identifier for UTC
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T09:30:00.0z"
 }

"start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-11T03:30:00-06:00" //-06:00 would be UTC offset
},
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-11T04:30:00-06:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [google calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), you'll notice that event `dateTime`'s must be passed in the RFC 3339 format (as you're already aware of based on the example you gave in your question).

The [specification for the rfc 3339 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) states:

> Because the daylight saving rules for local time zones are so
> convoluted and can change based on local law at unpredictable times,
> true interoperability is best achieved by using Coordinated Universal
> Time (UTC).  This specification does not cater to local time zone
> rules.

which basically means that this specification does not account for DST. Basically you're responsible for adjusting for DST on your end before passing a date to the Google Calendar API.